# Problemas llamando un parametro en una pagina jsp

Tags: java, jsp

me encuentro haciendo una Web Page muy sencilla la cual es factorizar el numero indicado por el usuario. Pero al momento de llamar la pagina me aparece un error y ese error me lo indica en la linea indicada por: `int n = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));` Que estoy haciendo mal o si me falta algo, les muestro mi codigo y el error a continuacion:

```
<body>
        <h1>Calculo Factorial</h1>
        <form action="tercerjsp.jsp" method="POST">
            Ingresa un numero: <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="enviarDato">
        </form>
        <% 
        
            
        int n = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));
        
        int factorial = 1;
        
for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    factorial = factorial * i;
}
        out.println("El factorial de "+n+" es: "+factorial);        
        
        
        %>
    </body>
```

[image: Error de la imagen]

Comment: tu formula de factorial es incorrecta, empieza por cambiar eso

Answer (score 1):

El error creo que esta en que no validas que request.getParameter("numero") sea diferente de null ya que cuando haces la solicitud por primera vez a /tercerjsp.jsp este parametro es null . Lo que unico que tienes que hacer es poner

```
    if(request.getParameter("numero")!=null) {   /*este condicional*/
    int n = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));
     int factorial = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
    factorial = factorial * i;
   }
    out.println("El factorial de "+n+" es: "+factorial);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. Buenas Juan tienes varios errores te comento si lo que pretendes es 
    mostrar los datos en un jsp no puedes usar las instrucciones de
    out.println y las declaraciones y expresiones se ponen entre <% %>.
    Paso 1) Crear un  formulario con código html es lo mas recomendable
    ejemplo

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
       <h1>Calculo Factorial</h1>
            <form action="factorial.jsp" method="POST">
                Ingresa un numero: <input type="text" name="numero" id="numero">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="enviarDato">
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    Paso 2) Crear el factorial.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          
            <%int n = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("numero"));  
            
            int factorial = 1; %>
            
              <%for(int i=n; i>1; i--) {%>
              <%factorial=factorial*i; %>
                
             <%} %>
              <p>El factorial del numero:<%=n %> es: <%=factorial %></p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
    

 2. Recuerda modularizar tus proyectos para que sea mas sencillo y no le
    pongas de nombre a un jsp como tercerjsp.jsp no es recomedable. Con
    esto ya te funciona el ejercicio Un saludo.
```